# Recursive function with array

Tags: ruby

I have an array with the following example definition:

```rb
segments = [["000", "001", "002"], ["110", "111", "112"], ["210", "211", "212"]]
```

This array can have any number of elements and each element will have an array.

I am trying to generate the following output:

```
000-110-210
000-110-211
000-110-212
000-111-210
000-111-211
000-111-212
000-112-210
000-112-211
000-112-212
001-110-211
001-110-212
001-111-210
001-111-211
001-111-212
001-112-210
001-112-211
001-112-212
.
.
.
```

I cannot figure out the logic to get this done.

Comment: @Stefan answer is what I was looking for.

Comment: result = base_structure_combinations[0].product(*base_structure_combinations[1..-1])result = result.map { |arr| [arr.join('-')] }

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [`Array#product`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.1/Array.html#method-i-product):

```
combined = segments[0].product(*segments[1..-1]) 
#=> [["000", "110", "210"], ["000", "110", "211"], ["000", "110", "212"],
#    ["000", "111", "210"], ["000", "111", "211"], ["000", "111", "212"],
#    ["000", "112", "210"], ["000", "112", "211"], ["000", "112", "212"],
#    ["001", "110", "210"], ["001", "110", "211"], ["001", "110", "212"],
#    ["001", "111", "210"], ["001", "111", "211"], ["001", "111", "212"],
#    ["001", "112", "210"], ["001", "112", "211"], ["001", "112", "212"],
#    ["002", "110", "210"], ["002", "110", "211"], ["002", "110", "212"],
#    ["002", "111", "210"], ["002", "111", "211"], ["002", "111", "212"],
#    ["002", "112", "210"], ["002", "112", "211"], ["002", "112", "212"]]
```

Or more explicitly (if the number of arrays is fixed):

```
combined = segments[0].product(segments[1], segments[2])
```

Use [`join`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.1/Array.html#method-i-join) to join the sub arrays:

```
combined.map { |arr| arr.join('-') }
#=> ["000-110-210", "000-110-211", "000-110-212", ...]
```

Comment: Learned a new thing. :)

Comment: If you give a block, product will yield all combinations. So wouldn't it be costly using map explicitly? (-- learning)

Comment: @SharvyAhmed a block works fine to output each combination. But if you need an array for further processing, you'd use `map`.

Comment: ...or, if `segments` can be mutated: `segments.shift.product(*segments)`.

Answer (score 1):

If you just need result - use @Stefan answer. If this is just start of smth bigger and/or you want to understand how to do it yourself:

```
segments = [["000", "001", "002"], ["110", "111", "112"], ["210", "211", "212"]]

def generate(segments, i, cur)
  if i == segments.count
    puts cur.join("-")
    return
  end

  0.upto(segments[i].count - 1) do |j|
    cur << segments[i][j]
    generate(segments, i + 1, cur)
    cur.pop
  end
end

generate(segments, 0, [])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Array#product`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.1/Array.html#method-i-product) which will give you the cross product of arrays. When given a **block**, product will yield all combinations and return self instead.

Try this:

```
combinations = []
segments.first.product(*segments[1..-1]) { |arr| combinations << arr.join("-") }
```

The output will be:

```
combinations
=> ["000-110-210", "000-110-211", "000-110-212", "000-111-210", "000-111-211", "000-111-212", "000-112-210", "000-112-211", "000-112-212", "001-110-210", "001-110-211", "001-110-212", "001-111-210", "001-111-211", "001-111-212", "001-112-210", "001-112-211", "001-112-212", "002-110-210", "002-110-211", "002-110-212", "002-111-210", "002-111-211", "002-111-212", "002-112-210", "002-112-211", "002-112-212"]
```